# Memory leak in Google Chrome when changing an img src attribute repeatedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, memory-leaks

I'm having a serious issue with Google Chrome only. The problem happens when I change the src attribute of an img tag with javascript.

This is the scenario. I'm developing a React website for a photographer. The site has a Gallery section and when you click in one picture it changes the src attribute of another one so you can see it in 1:1 scale. There is no problem to do this once or twice, etc.. but when you do this, maybe 10 times, Chrome becomes very, very slow, so I think it is an issue of memory in google chrome (maybe a browser bug).

Is there any way to improve the code or a way to tell Chrome to empty the memory everytime that I click a new image to change the src attribute of the other one?

Thanks in advance!

P.S: sorry if my English is not good enough! _:)

Comment: Changing an image's src 10 times shouldn't cause a memory drain. Please include a [mcve] of the code that is causing the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Please show your code and memory usage